# HTTP Post cutting off string

Tags: c#, http, post

I am using the following code to do a HTTP Post. This works fine in most cases but is cutting off my strings at a certain length something around 4300 string characters. How can I get around this problem? I have a hunch that this is related to all of the data not getting posted and getting cut off during the post. How can I get around this problem?

```
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
                // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("<URL>");
                // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
                request.Method = "POST";
                // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
                string postData = "json=" + json;
                //string postData = "json=blah";
                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
                // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
                request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                // Get the request stream.
                Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                // Write the data to the request stream.
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                // Close the Stream object.
                dataStream.Close();
                // Get the response.
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                // Display the status.
                //Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
                // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
                dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                // Read the content.
                retVal = reader.ReadToEnd();

                // Clean up the streams.
                reader.Close();
                dataStream.Close();
                response.Close();
```

Comment: What is byteArray.Length? Do you have the right data BEFORE writing it to the request stream?

Comment: The code looks ok to me, except he ```json``` parameter should be urlencoded.  Depending on what your data looks like, that might be the problem.

Comment: what web server? if IIS go to serverfault.com and ask about IIS configuration. IIRC there is a default setting in urlscan.ini (IIS6) or the metabase  that limits the sizes of posted data.

Comment: It's identical to the example here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx. The allowed post size should be more than 4000 characters (from memory it's around 10MB? That might be for a file upload though)

Comment: Agree with @SteveCampbell: `Uri.EscapeDataString(json)` is absolutely required.

Comment: That Uri.EscapeDataString(json) did the trick. Thanks so much for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That Uri.EscapeDataString(json) did the trick.